# How to apply distance-based clustering or dimensionality reduction for too many samples

Tags: r, clustering, matlab, dimensionality-reduction, large-data

I have a dataset with 200K samples (cases) and 30 variables. Every distance-based method for clustering or dimension reduction technique that I use, such as *DBSCAN*, *Hierarchical Clustering*, *LLE*, *Isomap* and ... fail to run on my machine (normally I get `R Session Terminated` error) due to the large distance file being generated. (*Distance calculation requires o(n^2) time and space*)

Is there any solution to handle this problem? Is there any good package for the mentioned clustering or dimensionality reduction in R or Matlab that is suitable ?

Comment: How many clusters?

Comment: 60 to 70 clusters

Comment: Use better implementations. For example, try DBSCAN in ELKI with index acceleration. It does not need O(n^2) memory and was 100x faster than R `fpc`.

Comment: You are speaking of distance-based clustering but, at the same time, requesting not to mess with the square distance matrix. This looks contradictory at first glance. Perhaps what you want is a special form of storage of the big matrix?

Comment: @ttnphns well, there *are* quite a lot of distance-based clustering algorithms that do not require a square distance matrix.

Comment: That's how my last sentence implied. Pairwise distance matrix can be organized and stored as, for example, adjacency list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Mini-Batch K-Means](https://algorithmicthoughts.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/machine-learning-mini-batch-k-means/). I have Matlab code for it:

```
function [c,counts,idx] = mbkmeans(x,k,c,counts)
    [N,D] = size(x);
    if ~exist('c','var') || isempty(c)
        c = x(1:min([k N]),:) + bsxfun(@times,randn(min([k N]),D)*0.001,std(x));
        if N < k
            c(N+1:k,:) = bsxfun(@plus,mean(x),bsxfun(@times,randn(k-N,D),std(x)));
        end;
    end;
    if ~exist('counts','var') || isempty(counts)
        counts = zeros(k,1);
    end;
    idx = knnsearch(c,x,'k',1);
    add = full(sparse(idx,1,1));
    counts(idx) = counts(idx) + add(idx);
    lr = 1 ./ counts(idx);   
    for i = 1:N
        c(idx(i),:) = (1 - lr(i)) * c(idx(i),:) + lr(i) * x(i,:);
    end;
```

Usage:

```
clusters = mbkmeans(yourdata,numberofclusters);
```

You may feed it your entire dataset at once and you're done. Or you may feed it smaller subsets. In this case, use it like this:

```
[c1, counts1] = mbkmeans(subset1,numberofclusters);
[c2, counts2] = mbkmeans(subset2,numberofclusters, c1, counts1); %start clustering using previously created clusters
[c3, counts3] = mbkmeans(subset3,numberofclusters, c2, counts2);
...
[cn, countsn, indices] = mbkmeans(subsetn,numberofclusters, c(n-1), counts(n-1));
```

For R, there is the [stream package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stream/) (explanation [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/massive-online-data-stream-mining-with-r/)). You may also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919129/k-means-in-matlab-is-out-of-memory-depending-on-the-distance-function), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#Complexity) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_clustering).

Comment: Regular k-means should be fine too, it also does not use pairwise distances. But k-means isn't on hist wish list, he probably already tried that... minibatch then does not help.

Comment: Just like @Anony-Mousse said, k-means works fine. I would like to know if I can apply any `distance-based` technique to my dataset.

Comment: So you should look at the second 'this' in my answer. It shows that DBScan does not need to store the entire distance matrix, so your problem is implementation specific.

Comment: This is the syntax of the DBScan algorithm in R: dbscan(data, eps, MinPts, scale, method, seeds, showplot, countmode)
What you need to change is the 'method' parameter:

method: Configures memory usage by constraining performance, there are three options:
"raw": treats data as raw data and avoids calculating a distance matrix (saves memory but may be slow).
"dist": treats data as distance matrix (relatively fast but memory expensive).
"hybrid": expects also raw data, but calculates partial distance matrices (very fast with moderate memory requirements.

Comment: @rcpinto thanks for your informative comment. I will try these options and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @rpcinto "very fast" is a gross overstatement in that documentation. This DBSCAN implementation is still incredibly slow!